# Python program fails after build with cx_Freeze in Windows

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I have a Windows desktop Python 3.9 program using wx and ObjectListView for user forms interaction.
When I run the program **inside VSCode all is working fine**.
Running the exe after building with cx_Freeze, the program fails on this line:

```
for attr in self.record.__table__.columns._data.keys():
```

This is the Class up to this line:

```
class AddModForm(wx.Dialog):
    """
    Opens a single-record form for add/update of record.
    dict is a dictionary of the object to work on (defined in globalvariables.py).
    """

    def __init__(self, targetObject, olv_dict, row=None, titlePrefix="Add", titleLabel="Record", addRecord=True):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, None, title="{} {}".format(titlePrefix, titleLabel))

        self.targetObject = targetObject
        self.olv_dict = olv_dict
        self.addRecord = addRecord
        self.selectedRow = row

        lblSize = (80,-1)
        txtSize40 = (40, -1)
        txtSize60 = (60, -1)
        txtSize80 = (80, -1)
        recordToUpdate = {}
        if self.selectedRow: # if updating - fetch record
            self.recordId = self.selectedRow.id
            self.record = forms_controller.getRecordByKey(targetObject, {"id": self.recordId})
            # arrange record attributes in a dictionary:
            for attr in self.record.__table__.columns._data.keys():
                recordToUpdate.update({attr: getattr(self.record, attr)})
```

Up to this line, the program runs OK, including opening and interacting through user forms, database interaction etc.

This Class is called following a button click by the user, called in this line (in another Class):

```
self.modifyForm = form_addmod.AddModForm(Departments, globalvariables.dict_olv_departments, selectedRow, "Update", "Department", False)
```

As far as the user experience, the button is clicked but the called form just won't open. No error is shown.

For reference, this is the setup.py for the build:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["configparser", "pymysql", "sqlalchemy", "ObjectListView", "validate_email", "wx"],
                     "include-files": ["etc\configuration.txt", "backup_db"]}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"


includefiles = ['etc\\']
includes = []
excludes = ['Tkinter']
packages = ["configparser", "pymysql", "sqlalchemy", "ObjectListView", "validate_email", "wx"]

setup(
    name = 'Employees Management',
    version = '1.0',
    description = '...',
    author = '...',
    author_email = 'info@...',
    options = {'build_exe': {'includes':includes,'excludes':excludes,'packages':packages,'include_files':includefiles}},
    executables = [Executable(script="main.py", base=base, icon="media\LAVI.ico", targetName="Employees Management.exe")]
)
```

This program used to work perfect on Python 3.6.5. I just needed a small fix, and re-installing some libraries again (probably for versions compatibility).

Any idea where can I look for? any known issues with cx_Freeze build process or runtime on Windows with this statement? maybe referencing the **Table** object?

Comment: "the program fails on this line"—what does "fails" mean? Presumably there's an actual error message? Please copy the exact, complete error message into your question. See [ask].

Comment: Thanks! I added to the question. No error, the called Class should open a form - it's just not opening.

Comment: Are you entirely sure that `self.record.__table__.columns._data.keys()` isn't empty? Without any values the loop body won't execute. You might want to add some logging to this so you can see what's happening. A debugger would be better, but I'm not sure how you can debug your code after building with `cx_Freeze`...

Comment: As this works perfectly within the IDE (VSCode), I'm sure the object is popoulated. It's just the build of the executable that breaks something. I identified this line using alerts (dialogs) to the user.

Comment: "As this works perfectly within the IDE (VSCode), I'm sure the object is popoulated"—careful with your assumptions. Lots of things could have changed between your development environment and your frozen code.

Comment: Very well. How can I further debug this?

Comment: Like I said, adding some logging would help. I'm not sure if you can run with `pdb` or another debugger somehow.